# Perl Regex issue

Tags: regex, perl

I was trying a random regex:

```
$string = "sajdk3:jdk3:jdk3:dgklmhij";
@arr = split(/([\da-z]+)([:;])\1\2\1/, $string);

# As per my understanding of RegEx, the given pattern shall match jdk3:jdk3:jdk3
# So @arr must contain two scalar values: 'sa' and ':dgklmhij'
# But when I printed @arr I got something else
print "Array: @arr\nNumber of items: ", scalar @arr;
#Array: sa jdk3 : :dgklmhij
#Number of items: 4

# So, I tried: 
$string =~ /([\da-z]+)([:;])\1\2\1/;
print "\n( $1 ) ( $2 )\n";
print "($`)($&)($') \n";
# ( jdk3 ) ( : ) (  ) (  ) (  ) 
# (sa)(jdk3:jdk3:jdk3)(:dgklmhij)
```

Can someone explain why the array has 4 elements, instead of 2?

Okay, so after the explanation of @mpapec, I'm curious how to accomplish it.
What shall one do when having a capturing group is unavoidable in the `split` param.
Like you want to split a date which can be `12-05-92` or `26.11.87` or `07 04 92`.

Comment: You use your first regex as the first param to `split`. You don't do that in your second example. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Technically, `split` looks not for delimiters (which surround things) but for separators (which come between them).  A parenthetical statement is *delimited* by open and close parens, a list like this is comma-*separated*, and a sentence is period-*terminated*.  Oddly, I don’t know what it’s called when the sentinel comes at the front of something the way a terminator comes at the end.

Comment: @innaM I am only having a `split`. What are you referring to by "second example"? Probably you mean `$string =~ /([\da-z]+)([:;])\1\2\1/;`
When the `split` didn't work as I'd expected, I tried to print what perl is interpreting of my regex. That's all.

Comment: `split /\D/, $date;` should work for your examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain why the array has 4 elements, instead of 2?

You're capturing delimiters as well when splitting, so there are 4 elements instead of 2.

From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

> If the PATTERN contains capturing groups, then for each separator, an additional field is produced for each substring captured by a group...